# How do I flatten JSON data in Redshift?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I want to bring this JSON data into a Redshift table with product, price and quantity columns. How should I make use of Redshift's JSON functions to do so?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/json-functions.html

`{ "lamp": { "price": 18.99, "quantity": 30 }, "desk": { "price": 129.99, "quantity": 12 }, "vase": { "price": 22.49, "quantity": 18 }, "speakers": { "price": 49.99, "quantity": 50 } }`

I've tried using the JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT function but I'm not sure how to apply it to this data (can it use wildcards, for example, to do the iteration?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON_PARSE instead of JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT, it returns super data type that can easily access to json objects.
I don't know where you take data from, but here is my example.

Create table with you example:

```
create table test.temp_json
(
    json_super super
);
insert into test.temp_json
values (json_parse('{ "lamp": { "price": 18.99, "quantity": 30 }, "desk": { "price": 129.99, "quantity": 12 }, "vase": { "price": 22.49, "quantity": 18 }, "speakers": { "price": 49.99, "quantity": 50 } }'))
```

Access data:

```
select key as product, value.price as price, value.quantity as quantity
from test.temp_json j,
     UNPIVOT j.json_super AS value AT key;
```

Result:

- lamp, 18.99, 30
- desk, 129.99, 12
- vase, 22.49, 18
- speakers, 49.99, 50

Read more about json_parse and unpivot
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_PARSE.html an
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html#unpivoting